# does anyone know any forks i can fit on my specialized pitch XC bike

Tags: fork

so I'm looking to get a new for fork for my Specialised pitch, and it's a quick release wheel so need quick release forks, does anyone know any forks?

Comment: If you're happy to buy a new fork, then consider a new front wheel with a through axle too.

Comment: If its QR, its likely straight steerer 26", very old school and getting hard to find in decent quality. You will find forks from off-brand and low-mid range manufacturers - mostly likely the best you will get si something from Suntour.  Used (good condition) forks are usually the best option of you can find some.  Do a search, I am sure this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more info on the year, make, model and size of your bike would be helpful. Assuming you're talking about a suspension fork, you'll want to make sure to get one with matching wheel diameter and axle type and width and brake type, and that the axle-to-crown distance is similar so the front doesn't tilt to far up or down compared with your current fork. As mattnz pointed out, you will also need to make sure that the steerer tube is the same type (straight or tapered) and the same outer diameter as your current one.

Comment: More important than all the things you listed is the the steerer -1 1/8th was common until tapered came in, but there were 1 1/2". Matching to existing wheels/brakes or replacing those fittings  comes second finding a fork with a matching steerer.